# How to bend the object inside a torus?

Tags: animation, mesh, armature, bones

I have an extruded torus empty inside and an object - electrode that I want to insert inside this torus to make animation. The electrode should bend inside when touching the inner walls of the torus and follow its curvature. I know how to bend the object along the path and can make the animation but I do not want this solution - rather I would like to use rigid body systems/ bones to make some simulations with different values. I tried them with no effect. Do you have any ideas what approach should I use? Is it ever possible?

[image: torus]

Comment: I don't think that you can make an object bent with rigid body physics. It's called *rigid* body for a reason. You could try cloth simulation. But the collision detection will probably go crazy. Maybe try a curve ;-) Bones can follow a curve but the result will be more like a train. Perhaps bendy bones can do the trick...?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will try bendy bones then.